# Excel: Find top values that sum to greater than or equal to N

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a series of unsorted values and I need to identify the top values that sum to at least 50. I want to then use this in a formula somehow to count the number of associated "yes" and "no" values.

Here is some example data:

[image]

In case of ties I want to include all the duplicate values in my final result. So in this example the top values are 40, 10 and 10 and my final result would be 1 yes and 2 no's.

I know I can use the LARGE function to get the nth top value so I tried fetching the top values in a separate range and then calculating the running sum:

[image]

I could then create a formula to find the row at which the sum reaches >= 50. Now the problem is how to get the yes/no values associated with the numbers and how to deal with ties.

Any ideas would be appreciated! Even better would be a simpler formula without all the intermediate steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will find your count:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$7=H2)*(ISNUMBER(MATCH($B$1:$B$7,INDEX(E:E,2):INDEX(E:E,MATCH(50,F:F)),0))))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks! This almost solved the problem, however, this formula does not work if the sum is not exactly 50. I need the top values that sum to greater than or equal to 50. I solved this by adding another column next to my running sum with the formula `= F2 >= 50` (copied down) and then changing your formula so the last MATCH becomes `MATCH(TRUE, G:G)`